# How to determine the tree of files which are imported during a test case?

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependencies, go-toolchain

When I run a test in Go, is there any way for me to get the list of files that the code imports, directly or indirectly? For example, this could help me rule out changes from certain parts of the codebase when debugging a failing test.

Alternatively, with Git, can we find out what the lowest common ancestor git tree node is for the files exercised in a given test?

Context: I'm looking into automated flakiness detection for my test suite, and I want to be able to know the dependency tree for every test so that I can detect flaky tests better.

For example, if `TestX` fails for version `x` of the code, and later on some files in the same codebase which are not used at all by `TestX` are changed, and then `TestX` passes, I want to be able to detect that this is a flaky test, even though the overall codebase that the test suite ran on has changed.

Comment: With Go modules you do not have changes in dependencies. For the rest go list might be what you are looking for. But this smells like a XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for `go list -test -deps [packages]`.

For an explanation of what the flags do, you can check Go command [List packages or modules](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-List_packages_or_modules):

`-deps`:

> The `-deps` flag causes list to iterate over not just the named packages but also all their dependencies. It visits them in a depth-first post-order traversal, so that a package is listed only after all its dependencies. [...]

`-test`:

> The `-test` flag causes `list` to report not only the named packages but also their test binaries (for packages with tests), to convey to source code analysis tools exactly how test binaries are constructed. The reported import path for a test binary is the import path of the package followed by a ".test" suffix, as in "math/rand.test". [...]

Maybe I'll state the obvious, but remember that `list` works on packages, not single files, so the command above will include dependencies of the non-test sources (which should be what you want anyway).